# Query not working when looking for null values on the where clause

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause, isnull

I got this query that works perfectly:

```
SELECT FOLDER.folderid, FOLDER.foldername
FROM FOLDER
INNER JOIN COLLABORATORS ON COLLABORATORS.folderid = FOLDER.folderid
WHERE COLLABORATORS.userid = 23
```

But when I added this on the where clause: "and FOLDER.parent = NULL" it doesnt work. The complete query is:

```
SELECT FOLDER.folderid, FOLDER.foldername
FROM FOLDER
INNER JOIN COLLABORATORS ON COLLABORATORS.folderid = FOLDER.folderid
WHERE COLLABORATORS.userid = 23 and FOLDER.parent = NULL
```

Does anyone know whats going on? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when dealing with `NULL`, you cannot use `=` or `<>` since the values are **unknown** but instead use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`,

```
WHERE COLLABORATORS.userid = 23 and FOLDER.parent IS NULL
```

- [MySQL - Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change this query

```
WHERE FOLDER.parent = NULL
```

to

```
WHERE FOLDER.parent IS NULL
```

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

[MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

For fetching Null Records from a table, it is required to use where [column] is null.
the condition specified in your query FOLDER.parent = NULL, will look for 'NULL' String(word) in the required column.
you can check this by inserting 'NULL' string(word) in the above column.